# Get rid of absolute paths from coverage.xml report generated by coverage.py

Tags: coverage.py

Is there a way to get relative paths to resulted coverage.xml (or strip off prefix) using coverage.py?

Answer (score 1):

Since [coverage v5.0.4](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/5.0.4/) you can set the `relative_files` option to `True`, e.g. in your `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
relative_files=True
```

See [this documentation section](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#run-relative-files) for reference and [this Github issue](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/948) for context.

Answer (score 0):

I could only manage to sed the console output. The bash code below will expand "../myrootmodule" and remove it from the coverage output. It will also adjust the spaces to preserve the columns alignment. You must **adjust the myrootmodule** path (first line only).

```
prefix="$$(readlink -e $$(dirname $$(pwd)))/myrootmodule/"; \
            coverage report \
            | sed "s|$$prefix||" \
            | sed "s/^-\{$${#prefix}\}//" \    
            | sed "s/^Name \{$${#prefix}\}/Name/" \
            | sed "s/^TOTAL \{$${#prefix}\}/TOTAL/"
```

As it is big, I include it in tests/Makefile.